# How can I use CSS to create a horizontal gradient with multiple color stops?

Tags: html, css

The following code:

```
<style>
h1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, green, blue); 
} </style>
```

Will give me the standard color spectrum with horizontal lines.  I am trying to change the orientation of the lines so that they are vertical.  I have tried:

```
<style>
h1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(left, red, green, blue); 
} </style>
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, red, green, blue);
```

only miss out the to on browser specifics

```css
h1{background: linear-gradient(to left, red, green, blue); }
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't go wrong with this site, put in all of the colors you want, choose the positions of the stops and it will generate all of the browser specific code for you.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: This is the best way after you understand how everything works with the CSS syntax. This also includes IE support.